# How to get details information about *gin.Context.Request.Context()

Tags: go, trace, go-gin, open-telemetry

I'm trying to use [otelgin](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-go-contrib/tree/main/instrumentation/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/otelgin) to trace my project, and it's says that `where required. It is available from gin.Context.Request.Context()`, so how can i get the detail information from gin.context to see if it works.

Officially, they add a stdout as the exporter when init tracer provider:

```golang
func initTracer() (*sdktrace.TracerProvider, error) {
    // stdout as exporter
    exporter, err := stdout.New(stdout.WithPrettyPrint())
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    tp := sdktrace.NewTracerProvider(
        sdktrace.WithSampler(sdktrace.AlwaysSample()),
        sdktrace.WithBatcher(exporter),
    )
    otel.SetTracerProvider(tp)
 
otel.SetTextMapPropagator(propagation.NewCompositeTextMapPropagator(propagation.TraceContext{}, propagation.Baggage{}))
    return tp, nil
}
```

here is part of the command line output:

```
"Name": "/users/:id",
    "SpanContext": {
        "TraceID": "e7a43d30c0e507b4c59fd65dc3bc6d77",
        "SpanID": "636c22201c903573",
        "TraceFlags": "01",
        "TraceState": "",
        "Remote": false
    },
    "Parent": {
        "TraceID": "00000000000000000000000000000000",
        "SpanID": "0000000000000000",
        "TraceFlags": "00",
        "TraceState": "",
        "Remote": false
    },
    "SpanKind": 2,
    "StartTime": "2022-11-12T16:02:07.871843+08:00",
    "EndTime": "2022-11-12T16:02:07.871843+08:00",
```

But is there any way to get this form gin.Context? Or can I get the exporter's detail information from gin.Context? I have tried to add a middleware to capture them below:

```golang
func TracerGetMiddleware(c *gin.Context) {
    //var tracer oteltrace.Tracer
    //tracerInterface, ok := c.Get("otel-go-contrib-tracer")
    //if ok {
    /// tracer, ok = tracerInterface.(oteltrace.Tracer)
    //}
    //tracer.Start(c, "test")
    fmt.Println(c.Request.Context())
}
```

But this is output of c.Request.Context()

```
(type *http.contextKey, val <not Stringer>).WithValue(type *http.contextKey, val [::1]:8088).WithCancel.WithCancel.WithValue(type trace.traceContextKeyType, val <not Stringer>)
```

Comment: To see if it works, you could initialize the tracer with output on stdout. Assuming you create a `gin` instance, add the `otelgin` middleware, and handle GET routing, you could use a `tracer.Start` call in your provided handler function. There you would specify your `c.Request.Context()`. Then you would start the server, e.g. type `wget http://localhost:8080/users/42` on the command line (adjust server and port to your configuration) or use a tool like Postman to simulate a client call. Then you would see something similar on stdout on your server that you posted.

Comment: If it doesn't work as expected, you could maybe edit your question and add a minimal, reproducible example (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  that would make it easier for people here to help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. When I asked the question, I didn’t have a deep understanding of otelgin. I wanted to customize a similar official exporter for testing (but the output information is less and more critical)
Now that I think about it, I wonder if this is even necessary. At the same time, is there any learning documentation about this library? All I can find is the official library and some simple samples, but sometimes it is not clear what he is doing every step of the way. For example, tracer.Start call must be used in the handler function so thar can be used normally?thx

Comment: As for the documentation: you may have seen it already, concepts about OpenTelemetry can be found here: https://opentelemetry.io/docs/concepts/, about basic instrumentation in the context of go https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/go/ - be sure to read https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/go/manual/.  Studying the examples is certainly good too. About OpenTelemetry Gin Middleware there are some blog posts. And if you get stuck somewhere on a particular detail, you can ask on Stackoverflow, preferably with a minimal, reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present, I understand the answer I originally wanted to get, which is to get traceID, SpanID and other data in gin.context

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    oteltrace "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/trace"
)

func GetIDMiddleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        if oteltrace.SpanFromContext(c.Request.Context()).SpanContext().IsValid() {
            TraceID := oteltrace.SpanFromContext(c.Request.Context()).SpanContext().TraceID().String()
            SpanID := oteltrace.SpanFromContext(c.Request.Context()).SpanContext().SpanID().String()
            fmt.Println(TraceID)
            fmt.Println(SpanID)
        }
    }
}
```

My initial idea was to pass trace information in the context through otelgin, and then capture traceID and so on through context in gin's middleware for zap logging, but at that time I didn't know how to get TraceID and other information, and when I saw [gin-contrib/zap](https://github.com/gin-contrib/zap/blob/master/_example/example02/main.go) library find the right way.